# getting distinct column name and count when based on another table

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

i have the following query:

```
select cc.category from companies c
left join categories cc on c.category_id = cc.category_id
where company_title like '%gge%';
```

which return categories with duplicate rows.
what i need is to get distinct categories, with the total count of accurences of that category,
something like:

CATEGORY NAME | XXX ( where XXX is the count )

anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query instead :-

```
select distinct cc.category,
count(cc.category) as totalCategoryCount
 from companies c
left join categories cc on c.category_id = cc.category_id
where company_title like '%gge%'
group by cc.category
```